# nvcc fatal : Compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH different than the one specified with -ccbin

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I've installed CUDA 7.5 on Windows 7-SP1 and I'm uisng Visual Studio 2013.
Unfortunately, I can't run any CUDA code. I can't even build the sample bandwidthTest. I get the following error:

> C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v7.5\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
>   Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code=\"sm_37,compute_37\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I./ -I../../common/inc -I./
>   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 
>   --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -Xcompiler "/wd 4819"     -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MT " -o x64/Release/bandwidthTest.cu.obj "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v7.5\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"  1>  **nvcc
>   fatal   : Compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH different than the one specified
>   with -ccbin** 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   7.5.targets(604,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code=\"sm_37,compute_37\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"**  -I./ -I../../common/inc -I./
>   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 
>   --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -Xcompiler "/wd 4819"     -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MT " -o x64/Release/bandwidthTest.cu.obj "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v7.5\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" exited with
>   code 1.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

My environment variables are:

**Path:**

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64**;**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin**;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\libnvvp;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Performance Advisor;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\i386\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common

**CUDA_PATH:**

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5

**CUDA_PATH_V7_5:**

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5

I also changed

> INCLUDES        +=  "-I$(TOP)/include" $(*SPACE*)

to

> INCLUDES += "-I$(TOP)/include" "-I$(TOP)/include/cudart" "-IC:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include" $(*SPACE*)

in **nvcc.profile**.

But no luck so far!! :(
Could you please help me?!
Thanks

Comment: It might worth mentioning that I've Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013 on my machine.

Comment: It should be fine, `nvcc` uses compiler toolset that is set in project properties (vc120 in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

There are thee versions of Visual Studio compiler: for x86, for x86_64 and ARM platforms (and I heard fourth is coming soon).

The problem is most likely comes from the fact that you are compiling for a  platform that is different from the compiler's platform you have in `PATH`.

**Solution**

You should never have Visual Studio's `bin` folders in your global `PATH` variable.

Remove everything related to Visual Studio from your `PATH`. Visual Studio IDE and CUDA tools are smart enough to find the compiler without your help (via registry entries).

If you want to run developer tools from the command line (without IDE) at the same time, use:

- Visual Studio Command prompt in Start menu (which uses `vcvarsall.bat` script)
- or use `vcvarsall.bat` directly (which temporarily sets up the environment for building against a platform given as a parameter)
- or roll out your own script

Comment: thanks Drop. I removed everything related to Visual Studio from PATH. But I still get the same error...

Comment: You need to restart Visual Studio (environment variables are being read on program startup)

Comment: I did @Drop. I also restarted my computer. But I still get the error

Comment: Well, that means that wrong things are somehow *still* in your `PATH`. You should manage to remove them. It's not really related to VS or CUDA. Try `echo %PATH%` in plain `cmd.exe` console. There should be no words `Visual` or `Studio` in the output. Try `cl`, it should not find it. Try `where cl` if it does. Check Project Settings -> VC++ Directories -> Executable directories as well.

Comment: Thanks a million. the problem was Bullseye (something that I use to check my code coverage and it has it's own cl.exe). I removed it from Executable Directories and now it complies. :-) THANKS again.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I'm running CUDA 6.5 and VS2013.  The cl.exe is not in the path.  If I remove the Executable Directories where cl.exe is located in the Properties then VS can't find cl.exe and I get an MSB6003 error.

Answer (score 1):

If the above answer doesn't work for you, here's what I did with Visual Studio 2013 and CUDA 6.5 for an x64 compile.

I edited

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.props
```

So that

```
<VCBinDir Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32'">$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x86)</VCBinDir>
<VCBinDir Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64)</VCBinDir>
```

Comment: But you need to also make sure that PATH points at the right MSVC compiler. Otherwise `nvcc` will complain that there is a discrepancy in the environment regarding compiler. In simple terms this means that even when you set `-ccbin` the `nvcc` will still look around, which imho is a very unwanted behaviour. Right now I am fighting with this same issues after finding the `CUDA 8.0.props` file (since this is the version I'm using) by searching for all CUDA related files on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the key cause of this problem is the name of **cl.exe** is duplicated. I have the BullseyeCoverage(a software which can analyze the fraction of coverage of code) installed. It have the same named **cl.exe** program. Then i uninstall it, the problem is gone！

Comment: I ran into this exact problem.  Instead of uninstalling BullseyeCoverage, I simply renamed the Bullseye directory to something else temporarily.  It's a bit of a hack, but it cured my issue.